# Blinking text in a textarea field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text area in a 404 page on my website that is a monologue from the webserver to the user. This text uses a `|` character to represent the 'cursor' position in the monologue. Unfortunately, this character does not blink. After googling around and finding http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_element#Implementation, I tried adding it to the page, but when I put the tags around the `|`, it shows as a literal instead of being interpreted.

The function for displaying the text is

```
      function type_text()
  {
    contents='';
    row=Math.max(0,index-7);
    while(row < index)
    {
      contents += tl[row++] + '\r\n';
    }
    document.forms[0].elements[0].value = contents + tl[index].substring(0,text_pos) + "<blink>|</blink>";
    if(text_pos++==str_length)
    {
      text_pos=0;
      index++;
      if(index!=tl.length)
      {
        str_length=tl[index].length;
        setTimeout("type_text()",1500);
      }
    } else
      setTimeout("type_text()",speed);
  }
```

This is of course in Javascript.

I used this to script the `<blink>` tags:

```
function blink() 
{
    var blinks = document.getElementsByTagName('blink');
    for (var i = blinks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        var s = blinks[i];
        s.style.visibility = (s.style.visibility === 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    }
window.setTimeout(blink, 500);
 }

  if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", blink, false);
  else if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", blink, false);
  else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", blink);
  else window.onload = blink;
```

If it helps at all, my page can be found here: http://paradoxwow.com/404.shtml I have a 'Test' message blinking in the bottom left, but the `|` won't blink.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A textarea cannot contain HTML, so you're out of luck there. Since you aren't really using the textarea for input, why use a textarea at all? Use a div instead, and modify your code appropriately.

Comment: But my problem is how would I get a div to scroll like a textarea would? I'm not very good with html/javascript. The Javascript that I have on the page, I copy/pasted from somewhere else and tweaked a bit.

Comment: A div can scroll in exactly the same way a textarea can. Set a fixed height for the div and insert `<br/>` tags instead of `\r\n` characters

Comment: @Asad - And set `overflow` to `scroll`.

Comment: @Derek If you look at how his page behaves currently, I think he needs the default `auto`, not `scroll`

Comment: I got it working. Didn't have to do either. I had to play around a bit with innerHTML, even though it's evil from what I've been told.

Answer (score 0):

The content of `textarea` is just text, so all markup is ignored (taken as text data). So you could make the entire content blink, but not just part of it.

It is illogical and pointless to use textarea when you are not expecting user input. You can use a `pre` element, inside which markup is recognized, though just a limited set of tags is allowed in principle, but you can use `blink` or styled `span` there. Alternatively, use a `p` or `div` with suitable styling, such as `white-space: pre`.